# Is it possible to kill a running CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Let us say I have numerous CUDA kernels that I can ask the GPU to execute. I don't want to modify the kernel code in anyway (to include a trap for eg).

Is there a way to kill such a running kernel?

I intend to auto generate kernels (Genetic Programming). These kernels are likely to have behavior where they may take a very long time to complete. If I can kill a kernel while it is running I can maintain a timer and kill if required.

Comment: Will you have to check the output of the kernels to determine if they should be killed? Then it makes more sense to use a regular model where you create kernels that run for brief periods of time and examine their output to determine if they should be relaunched.

Comment: In my use case the output cannot be interpreted to take actions. I need a mechanism to preempt as running kernel.

Comment: I think you are almost certainly on the wrong track in your design. If you manage to come up with a way to kill a running kernel, it will be a hack -- not something CUDA was designed to do. You should consider how you can modify your design in such a way that it works within the regular CUDA paradigm.

Answer (score 5):

[cudaDeviceReset()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gdcc2c6f914eb9461565b12648faa5e28) will kill any running kernel(s).

It will also wipe out any allocations done on the device, so you will need to re-allocate any data areas if you intend to use them again.

Note that `cudaDeviceReset()` by itself is insufficient to restore a GPU to proper functional behavior.  In order to accomplish that, the "owning" process must also terminate.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329377/reset-cuda-context-after-exception/56330491#56330491).